# How Can I setup Google Actions For Team Development?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am working with a team to develop a Google Action for an Organisation called 'Rocket Chat'. Now what we want to do is that, to create one main account under that organisation, where frontend and backend will be hosted and also give access of this account to a few Developers. What will be the most efficient way of doing this?. Any ideas or suggestions on how to do that are appreciated. Thanks.

Frontend is hosted on Dialogflow and for backed we are hosting our fulfilment on Firebase. If you want more details on our setup, please visit here => https://github.com/RocketChat/google-action-rocketchat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "correct" way to do it would be for every developer to use their own account, and [share a project](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/setup-and-developing#adding_collaborators) with all of them. This also will allow you to have more granular permissions for each developer.

In addition to having ownership of the project, you may also want to have some processes in place to mitigate potential issues. If everyone uses one project, it's possible to run into race conditions if multiple developers upload the same cloud function. The Dialogflow console also may have issues with multiple editors at one time.

For easier development, each developer may want their own separate prototyping project which gives them full control over the environment, and then have some way to integrate their changes into one master project.